# Spring Data Mongo DB: using upsert to update existing document's certain fields or insert whole document

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I cant seem to figure out how to EITHER insert a whole document OR update ONLY specific fields. I seem to either can: insert OR update every field or get an error. I have a test code like (using Jackson for converting to map):

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("transactionId").is("1234"));
YourDocumentClass document = new YourDocumentClass();
document.setSomething("test");
document.setTransactionId("1234");
document.setTransactionStatus("NEW");

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Object> fieldsToUpdate = objectMapper.convertValue(document, Map.class);

Update update = new Update();
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : fieldsToUpdate.entrySet()) {
    update.set(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}

mongoTemplate.upsert(query, update, YourDocumentClass.class);
```

This works fine for insert, but this also means the whole document gets updated when the record already exists.

I need only certain fields (in this test case lets say I want the "transactionStatus") to be updated. However setOnInsert and set together gives me errors (which would mean the natural way to me, but its apparently not):

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("transactionId").is("1234"));
YourDocumentClass document = new YourDocumentClass();
document.setSomething("test");
document.setTransactionId("1234");
document.setTransactionStatus("NEW");

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Object> fieldsToUpdate = objectMapper.convertValue(document, Map.class);

Update update = new Update();
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : fieldsToUpdate.entrySet()) {
    update.setOnInsert(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
update.set("transactionStatus", "APPROVED");

mongoTemplate.upsert(query, update, YourDocumentClass.class);
```

The problem here is that I set "transactionStatus" twice when inserting: however I need to insert the initial status on insert, and ONLY update the status when updating.

Is this possible with mongoTemplate with a single atomic operation? As this needs to be thread safe and I dont want to use thread locking when Mongo can lock the documents itself.

Thank you